# Prove integrability and equality

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of $X$ and let $\mu:\mathfrak{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a countably additive measure.$A \in \mathfrak{M}, \mu(A) = \mu(X), f \in L_1(A)$. Prove that $ f \in L_1(X)$ and $\int\limits_{X}{fd\mu} = \int\limits_{A}{fd\mu}$

Since $f$ is integrable on $A$ then it is measurable on this set, hence it is also measurable on $X$. Is not this enough to claim that it is also integrable on $X$?

How do I prove the equality? I do not need a complete solution. A hint is enough. Thank you

Comment: Does $f\in L_1(A)$ mean $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mathfrak{M}$?

Comment: Integrability implies measurability on $A$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assume that $f$ is measurable on $X$. $\int_X f\, d\mu=\int_A f \,d\mu+\int_{X\setminus A} f \,d\mu$ and the second term is $0$. [Any measurable function is integrable over a measurable set of measure $0$ and value of the integral is $0$].

Comment: Thank you. I should have noted this myself, but I am still too bad at solving such problems...

Comment: do we need to know that $\mu(A) = \mu(X)$ to infer that $f$ is integrable on $X$?

Comment: @DonDraper Yes. Otherwise there is no reason for $f$ to be intergable on $X$.

Comment: another question if you don't mind. Does the equality you in your post imply the integrability of $f$ on $X$? Or do we need to prove the integrability first and only then we have the right to make the conclusion? |
If so, what is the reasoning behind integrability on $X$? \

Comment: @DonDraper Befor writing the equation you have to use the fact that any function is integrable over a set of measure $0$. If $f$ is integrable over $A$ and its complement then it is intergable over $X$.